# Laravel - Call multiple templates in one Structure

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to add Multiple template in one Master structure. I try below code but it is not working. I also follow lots of question in Stack but did not find a right solution. If you have a solution share me. Thanks in Advance.

**Controller:**

```
class Harryandsally extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('layouts.master');
    }
}
```

**Structure: (app\view\layouts\master.blade.php)**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Harry & Sally</title>    
</head>
<body>    
<div class="container">
    @yield('harry')
</div>
<div class="block1">
    @yield('sally')
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Template: (app\view\harry.blade)**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('harry')
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Harry</td>
    </tr>
</table>
@stop
```

**Template: (app\view\sally.blade)**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('sally')
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Sally</td>
    </tr>
</table>
@stop
```

Comment: You probably want to use the `@setction` deinition. See Blade template documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to include Harry and Sally views?
If that's the case, you should use "include" => @include( 'harry' )

Here's an example:

layouts.master:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Harry & Sally</title>    
</head>
<body>    
<div class="container">
    @include('harry')
</div>
<div class="block1">
    @include('sally')
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

harry:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Harry</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

sally:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Sally</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my issue sort out by this
Passing A Sub-View To A View

Sometimes you may wish to pass a view into another view. For example, given a sub-view stored at app/views/child/view.php, we could pass it to another view like so:

$view = View::make('greeting')->nest('child', 'child.view');

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#Passing%20A%20Sub-View%20To%20A%20View

Comment: new for 5...   `@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])` is correct  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates